# pthread pause/wait conditions

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, pause

I have two threads that are communicating to a serial port. One thread is continuously polling the serial port. The polling is done by first writing to the serial port write("do you have a message") and then reading the reply. This has to happen in consecutively.

I have another thread that is used to send commands over the serial port. So all this thread is doing is writing a message to the port, and then reading a confirmation that the message was sent.

So, while one thread is used to read and another used to write, they both do a read() and write().

My issue is, my current implementation uses and read mutex and a write mutex, which of course means you can get a write, write, read, read ordering, which is not the behavior I want.

I tried only using one lock and encompassing the write/reads, but this is causing one thread (polling thread) to never let the other thread grab the lock, or it randomly happens, even if I put sleeps after an unlock of one thread.

So, is there a way to pause one thread... say after it's done a read/write combo, and let another thread do it's thing? What's the best way of going about this issue? I do not want to use pthread_join because 1. It will pause my main code that is creating these threads and 2. The polling thread is never meant to exit unless there is an error.

Thanks

Comment: Please, add a minimal sample code to illustrate your problem. (I guess in this case, the mutual exclution is your subject. Thus, it even need not to contain serial port access.)

Comment: You want to have a look a "*conditions*". The POSIX-API provides the `pthread_cond_*()` family of functions to use them.

Comment: In the meanwhile I am voting to close this question as being "*too broad*". The moment you are facing *specific* issue (probably with using the above mentioned API) you very welcome to come back here with ... well ...  - a *specific* question. ;-)